# How can I install Octave with curl support via homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I've installed octave with homebrew (via `brew install octave`), and it seems to work fine, including gnuplot support.  However, it looks like it's missing curl support.  I'm getting the message "`error: urlread: curl: No error`" when trying to execute `str = urlread(url, 'post', params)`.

I've tried making homebrew install curl by adding `depends_on 'curl'` to the octave formula and setting the CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS environment variables to point to homebrew curl, but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Is cURL in your path? What does `which curl` say?

Comment: Good point Ian.  Note that `curl` is part of Darwin so it *is* on the path.  It's installed on Macs by default in `/usr/bin/`.  If that is what the output of the call to `which` reports then it could be the issue. You could simply put an `alias` statement in your .bashrc to point to the homebrew install. Aliasing a call to curl will only work from the terminal (or something else that sources your .bashrc).

Comment: It's probably not actually shelling out to `curl`; it's using libcurl, according to the Octave readline doco at http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/URL-Manipulation.html. And it's probably finding libcurl fine, since it comes with the os like @ephsmith says. May be an error with the particular URL or parms combo. Does a simpler `str = urlread('www.example.com')` work? Try POSTing to some other simpler URLs?

Comment: Try using RequestBin (http://requestb.in/) to test it, so you can isolate the URL you're hitting from the `urlread` mechanism. A default Homebrew Octave install on OS X 10.8.3 works fine for me, hitting requestb.in with a post: `urlread('http://requestb.in/1c3x8id1', 'post', {'hello','world'})` succeeds.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem a while back that was caused by having my proxies set up funny. I ended up disabling them to get it to install.

Also, are you sure curl is installed correctly? You could try installing it manually as well: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html